# Thermal emission from a metal surface

Tags: radiation, thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation, photon-emission

We know from Kirchhoffs law that at thermal equilibrium the absorbance is equal to the emissivity. Let's consider some opaque layers of Al, Ag, Au for which I found reflectances at google:

[image: http://www.tydexoptics.com/optical_coatings/metal_mirrors/]

When I heat the layers to say 150 °C, I assume (correct me if wrong) that the reflectance does not change considerably.

What does this mean for the emissivity of the metal? For example, in the case of gold is it correct that I would see emission of around 0.8* (the emission  of a black body at 150°C) below ~250 nm and essentially no radiative power for longer wavelengths?

Comment: A wavelength of 250 nm is in the UV, there will be no significant emission there at 150 degrees.

Comment: yes, sure i see that the amount will be miniscule. it was only a conceptual question. thy anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each wavelength the emission is reduced by $1-R$ compared to a black body. This is assuming that the layer is thick enough to be opaque.